# error: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Werror=pointer-to-int-cast]

Tags: c, linux, pointers

Below is my link to complete code:
[code link][1]

> mm.c:543:7: error: cast from pointer to integer of different size
> [-Werror=pointer-to-int-cast]    if ((int)(ptr = mem_sbrk(size)) ==
> -1){
> ^

I am getting a warning but my testing system considers warning as a error

I checked similar answers but it doesn't solve my issue and the interesting fact is I copied this snippet from codebase which supposed to be working, so why I am getting the error.
[1]: https://onlinegdb.com/HHkE8FTov

Comment: Use `intptr_t` instead of `int`. This will be an integer type large enough to hold a pointer value.

Comment: This did the job.

Comment: Please be aware that the question should include all relevant code. Instead of providing a link to a ton of unrelated code, you should better include a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) directly into your question. If the link goes stale, your question becomes worthless.

Answer (score 3):

```
 if ((int)(ptr = mem_sbrk(size)) == -1){
```

Since `mem_sbrk` returns a `void *` and `ptr` is a `char *`, this only makes sense if `int`, `void *`, and `char *` are the same size. Even if that's true on your platform it's not good practice to rely on it.

You might want to replace `-1` with `((void *)-1)` instead of casting to an `int`, the standard practice when using `sbrk` and similar functions.